# parsing json with shell script

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing

Wanted to parse `json`:

`{"FileStatus":"accessTime":1472892839430,"blockSize":134217728,"childrenNum":0,"fileId":17226,"group":"admin","length":115714,"modificationTime":1469649837471,"owner":"admin","pathSuffix":"","permission":"755","replication":2,"storagePolicy":0,"type":"FILE"}}`

I tried something like this but not able to get it.

```
$ {"FileStatus":{"accessTime":1472892839430}} | jq '.FileStatus.accessTime'
```

Error:

```
-bash: {FileStatus:{accessTime:1472892839430}}: command not found`
```

Can someone help me to parse this whole `json`.

Comment: Use : `echo '{"FileStatus":{"accessTime":1472892839430}}' | jq '...'`

Answer (score 0):

To make a command read a string on stdin in bash, use a ["here string"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) like this:

```
$ jq '.FileStatus.accessTime' <<<'{"FileStatus":{"accessTime":1472892839430}}'
1472892839430
```

Also, you need to properly quote the text, so that bash doesn't try to interpret in some way you don't intend. When you want to preserve it literally, use [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes) (`'`).